# Editing .json with multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, json

I have a .json file that needs updating and I am having problems iterating through it. The .json file is of the format.

```
[
    {
        "name": {
            "first": "joe"
        },
    },
    {
        "name": {
            "first": "dave"
        },
    },
    {
        "name": {
            "first": "sarah"
        },
    }
]
```

I would like to edit the last dictionary from sarah to amber but I am having problems parsing the .json structure.

my code is as follows:

```
import json

with open('data.json') as file:
   data = json.load(file)
```

This loads the json file, but I am having trouble iterating over this file after loading it. `data[2]` yields the structure I am looking for but I am unsure how to edit the `{"first": "sarah"}` structure.

Comment: Have you used the `json` builtin library?

Comment: Show us the code you're using to parse the .json structure.

Comment: Ignore the fact that JSON is involved at all. It's just a list of nested dictionaries. How would you access `sarah` in that structure just as a plain python object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function:

```
def replace_first_name(people, old_name, new_name):
    for entry in people:
        if entry["name"]["first"] == old_name:
            entry["name"]["first"] = new_name
```

Call it with:

```
replace_first_name(data, "sarah", "amber")
```